# map on scala parallel collection doesn't react in REPL

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and I'm learning Scala's parallel collections.
I'm using Scala 2.12.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_272)

I want to compare the data-parallel collection with the normal one so I create two lists in the REPL:

```
val list = (1 to 10).toList
val parlist = (1 to 10).toList.par

list.map(_ + 42) 
# res1: List[Int] = List(43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52)
parlist.map(_ + 42)
# program hangs, no reaction and doesn't terminate.
```

I'm wondering why is the second case hanging?

Comment: This is a known problem with the REPL, that will work on a normal program or you can google for the fix in the REPL, it is flag.

Comment: Thanks, I found that post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Luis, this is a known problem with the REPL, some solutions are here:
https://github.com/scala/scala-parallel-collections/issues/34